# matlab for automatic differentiation

Tags: matlab, differentiation

if someone of you could help me out or point me in the right direction that would be wonderfull.

I have the following formula which has 8 parameters that differ for each subject. The equation describes a growth pattern with `t` being time and `y` being the growth. `m1` to `m8` are the parameters that differ for each subject

```
y = m1*(1-1/(1+(m2*(t+m8))^m5+(m3*(t+m8))^m6+(m4*(t+m8))^m7))
```

What i would like to do is insert this formula and calculate (numerically) the velocity curve. From this information i would like to obtain the following

- the maximum velocity and the corresponding age and height at that time
- the minimum velocity before the maximum velocity is reached.

and this in such a way that i just give a list of all my subjects and their parameters and just receive my results?

I have no background at all in programming and mathematics but i would like to be able to do this. I have matlab to my disposal. I'm trying to figure out how things work but i can't grip my head around it. As a biologist I will follow a programming course next year ;-)

Can anyone of you help me out.

Thanks

Update but still not there (thanks to you guys :-))

-I have made a tab delimited file derived from excel and having the following structure
column A: the ID of the subject
Colum B to I: the values of the different parameters m1 ... m8 (as in the equation)
each row is a different subject with different parameters

- I have chosen import selection and next generate function (or should i choose generate script).
- If i open this i see a new numbered tab appear. First line is afunction[ID,m1,...,m8]=importfile. then follow 112 lines.
- I have copied the text (thanks to dan) as given by dan starting from line 113.

  tmin=0;
  tmax=20;
  dt=1/12;
  t=timn:dt:tmax;
  y = m1.*(1-1./(1+(m2.*(t+m8)).^m5+(m3.*(t+m8)).^m6+(m4.*(t+m8)).^m7));
  dy=diff(y)./dt;
  max(dy);
  min(dy);
  imax=find(dy==max(dy))+1;
  imin=find(dy==min(dy))+1;
  t(imax);
  t(imin);
  y(imax);
  y(imin);

  - next i clicked run and was asked to save the file wich i've done.
  - now i clicked run again but i get an error

Anyone that can point me in the right direction??
Thanks a lot

Greetings

Comment: Where is the equation?

Comment: edited and function is included.

Comment: Where is `t` in your equation?

Comment: that was mo my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's a copy-pastable solution. The rest of my answer is the explanation :)

(You'll need [`FindRealRoots`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15122-real-roots-on-interval) from the FEX to run this).

```
trange = [tstart tend] % <your range in t>

% define all intermediate functions
a = m2^m5;
b = m3^m6;
c = m4^m7;
X = @(t) t(:).' + m8;

g   = @(t) 1 + [a b c] * bsxfun(@power, X(t), [m5; m6; m7]);
gp  = @(t) ([m5 m6 m7].*[a b c]) * bsxfun(@power, X(t), [m5-1; m6-1; m7-1]);
gpp = @(t) (([m5 m6 m7]-1).*[m5 m6 m7].*[a b c]) * ...
           bsxfun(@power, X(t), [m5-1; m6-1; m7-1]);
sgn = @(t) m1*(2*(gp(t)).^2 - g(t).^2*gpp(t) );

y   = @(t) m1*(1 + 1./g(t));   
yp  = @(t) -m1*gp(t) ./ g(t).^2;

% Find the roots of the derivative
R = FindRealRoots(gp, tstart , tend, 2*ceil(max([m5 m6 m7])));

% values at end-points
y0   = y(tstart);
yend = y(tend);

% if we have some roots, separate minima/maxima and sort
if ~isempty(R)

    extrema = y(R);
    signs   = sgn(R);

    % Find maximum
    [maximum, Imax] = max(extrema(signs < 0));
    tmax = R(Imax);

    if isempty(tmax) % no maximum in interval; use endpoint
        [~,ind] = max([y0, yend]);
        tmax = trange(ind);
    end

    ymax = y(tmax);


    % Find minimum *before* maximum
    [minima, Imin] = extrema(signs > 0); 
    tmin = R(Imin);

    if isempty(tmin) % no minimum on interval; use endpoint
        [~,ind] = min([y0, yend]);
        tmin = trange(ind);
    end

    if any(tmin < tmax)
        % make sure to take only one minimum; the one 
        % just before the maximum
        tmin = tmin(find(tmin < tmax, 1, 'last')); 
    else
        [~,ind] = min([y0, yend]);  % no minima before the maximum; use end-point
        tmin = trange(ind);
    end

    ymin = y(tmin);


else % no roots found; just order the end-points

    [ymax,ind] = max([y0, yend]); 
    tmax = trange(ind);

    [ymin,ind] = min([y0, yend]); 
    tmin = trange(ind);

end
```

Now, the explanation.

While the answer by Dan is a nice first step, I feel I must correct it in a few places.

For starters, numerical derivatives are computed as Dan describes them only when

- you have gridded data (the value of `y(t)` at a number of distinct points `t`)
- It is known that the underlying model function `y(t)` does not allow for interpolation

And this is simply not true in your case. When you have an explicit function that you can evaluate at any arbitrary point, numerical derivatives are best computed using [finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), and normally *only* when explicit derivatives cannot be found analytically.

As an example, the numerical derivative of `z = cos(x)` at `x = π/4` (using central differences with `h = 0.001`):

```
  z'(π/4) ≅ ( z(x+h)-z(x-h) ) / 2h                      
          = ( cos(π/4 + 0.001) - cos(π/4 - 0.001) ) / 0.002
          = -0.7071066633353995...
-sin(π/4) = -0.7071067811865475...   (value of analytical derivative)
```

Having said that, we move on to the more important point; the mathematics can be progressed **way further** than Dan did, before you have to resort to numerical methods. Doing so will perhaps be more tedious, but it will improve your understanding of the problem, of MATLAB, mathematics, and it will improve the accuracy and robustness of the outcomes.

For your function `y = f(t)`, you state you have 3 objectives:

1. Find the velocity curve
2. Find the maximum `y(t`<sub>`max`</sub>`) = y`<sub>`max`</sub>
3. Find the minimum `y`<sub>`min`</sub>, `t`<sub>`min`</sub> that occurs *before* the maximum `y`<sub>`max`</sub>

When translated into mathematical lingo:

1. Find the derivative `y' = dy/dt`
2. (and 3.) Find all roots `R` of `y'` and evaluate `y` and `y''` at all `R`, and also `y` at the initial time `t`<sub>`0`</sub>.

Let's start with objective 1. You have an explicit function of time `y = f(t)`, which is basically a variant form of a [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function),

```
    y(t) = a + f(t)/g(t)
```

For brevity, let's just drop the (t)-part. That's much easier to write, and it's understood that `y`, `f` and `g` all depend on `t`. So,

```
y = a + f/g
```

You have the advantage that `f(t) = <constant> = a = m1`, which facilitates things later on. The expression for the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of this kind of function takes this form (which is the [quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule)):

```
y' = (f'·g - f·g') / g²
```

and, since `f(t) = m1 = <constant>`, its derivative with respect to time is *zero*:

```
y' = -m1·g' / g²
```

Now, we need to find the derivative of `g`. The function `g` is the polynomial

`g = 1 + (m2·(t+m8))`<sup>`m5`</sup>`+ (m3·(t+m8))`<sup>`m6`</sup>`+ (m4·(t+m8))`<sup>`m7`</sup>

Let's define `X = t + m8`, `a = m2`<sup>`m5`</sup>, `b = m3`<sup>`m6`</sup> and `c = m4`<sup>`m7`</sup>. With this, `g` will look a lot less scary:

`g = 1 + a·X`<sup>`m5`</sup>`+ b·X`<sup>`m6`</sup>`+ c·X`<sup>`m7`</sup>

Differentiation of polynomials follows the [elementary power rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#The_polynomial_or_elementary_power_rule) (and [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), but that's not *really* relevant here because `X' = 1`):

`g' = m5·a·X`<sup>`m5-1`</sup>`+ m6·b·X`<sup>`m6-1`</sup>`+ m7·c·X`<sup>`m7-1`</sup>

and therefore,

`y' = -m1·g' / g² = -m1 · (m5·a·X`<sup>`m5-1`</sup>`+ m6·b·X`<sup>`m6-1`</sup>`+ m7·c·X`<sup>`m7-1`</sup>`) / (1 + a·X`<sup>`m5`</sup>`+ b·X`<sup>`m6`</sup>`+ c·X`<sup>`m7`</sup>`)²`

Objective 1 accomplished! You can now evaluate the velocity curve *anywhere* with full accuracy. Here's how to implement this function in MATLAB:

```
a = m2^m5;
b = m3^m6;
c = m4^m7;
X = @(t) t + m8;
dydt = @(t) -m1*( [m5*a m6*b m7*c]*X(t).^[m5-1; m6-1; m7-1] ) ./ ...
            ( 1 + [a b c]*X(t).^[m5; m6; m7] ).^2;
```

Now objective 2:

1. find all the [roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_solving) of `y' = 0`.
2. evaluate `y` on these roots
3. evalate `y''` on these roots
4. evaluate `y` on the end-points of the `t`-interval

Step 3. is necessary to determine whether a root `R` of `y' = 0` describes a *maximum* or a *minimum* of `y`. In case `y''(R) < 0`, you are dealing with a *maximum*, in case `y'' > 0`, a *minimum*, and `y''(R) = 0` you are dealing with an inflection point, which you may safely ignore for this problem.

Step 4. is necessary, because there may be cases where before the maximum, there is no minimum in the function, until way beyond the end point. in that case, the end point itself is the minimum you should use.

Now, step 1. If you look at the general shape of this equation,

```
y' = -m1·g' / g² = 0
```

it should be obvious that this is only possible if `g' = 0`. Therefore, we have to solve

```
g' = 0  =>
```

`m5·a·X`<sup>`m5-1`</sup>`+ m6·b·X`<sup>`m6-1`</sup>`+ m7·c·X`<sup>`m7-1`</sup>`= 0`

And it is only *now* that we are getting stuck with our mathematical progress. There is one trivial solution to this equation (`X = 0` (`t = -m8`)). However, there is only a *general* solution for specific values of the parameters `m5-7`. For all the other values of those parameters, no *general* solution exists and you'll have to find solutions numerically.

Therefore, I will recommend you to use

- [`roots`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) when `m5-7` are integers
- [`FindRealRoots`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15122-real-roots-on-interval) when they are not

For step 3, you repeat the process of taking derivatives one more time;

```
   y'  = -m1·g' / g²
=> y'' = m1·( 2·(g')² - g²·g'' ) / (g²)²
```

where

`g'' = (m5-1)·m5·a·X`<sup>`m5-2`</sup>`+ (m6-1)·m6·b·X`<sup>`m6-2`</sup>`+ (m7-1)·m7·c·X`<sup>`m7-2`</sup>. Note that you just need the *sign* of this, so only the numerator will suffice),

```
sgn(y'') = sgn( m1·( 2·(g')² - g²·g'' ) )
```

Here's how to do that in MATLAB:

```
g   = @(t) 1 + [a b c]*X(t).^[m5; m6; m7];
gp  = @(t) ([m5 m6 m7].*[a b c]) * X(t).^[m5-1; m6-1; m7-1];
gpp = @(t) (([m5 m6 m7]-1).*[m5 m6 m7].*[a b c]) * X(t).^[m5-1; m6-1; m7-1];
sgn = @(t) m1*(2*(gp(t)).^2 - g(t).^2*gpp(t) );
```

Then, with all roots `R` found previously, you just evaluate everything:

```
extrema = y(R);
signs   = sgn(R);
y0      = y(t0);
```

Now that you have all roots, all values of `y` at the roots and end-points, and all signs of the second derivative as well....

Objective 2 accomplished!

Comment: i'm getting the reason behind it but for some reason it won't work and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've pasted the script in the command window and uploaded my file in workspace where I inserted the colums i needed: the first being the name, colum 2 to 8 being the parameters. 
Or do i make a script and click run?

Answer (score 1):

If you equation is of the form: `y = f(t,...,... ...)` and all the other parameters are held constant over all time for each subject then you can do it like this.

First decide on a time range (so I'm going with 10 years, but that's totally dependent on your work):

```
tmin = 0;
tmax = 10;
```

Then you must choose a time resolution (I've gone with monthly, but you'll probably want something finer):

```
dt = 1/12;
```

Now create a `t` vector and solve for `y` numerically:

```
t = timn:dt:tmax;
y = m1.*(1-1./(1+(m2.*(t+m8)).^m5+(m3.*(t+m8)).^m6+(m4.*(t+m8)).^m7));
```

First order numerical differentiation is just finding the slope between each two consecutive points of `y`. I.E. `(y(i) - y(i - 1)) / (t(i) - t(i - 1))` and note that `t(i) - t(i - 1)` is always equal to `dt`. So in matlab we can just do this:

```
dy = diff(y)./dt;
```

but now `dy` has one less element than `dt` does. Keep this in mind.

So to find the max and min velocity:

```
max(dy);
min(dy);
```

and to find the corresponding times and heights:

```
imax = find(dy==max(dy)) + 1;
imin = find(dy==min(dy)) + 1;

t(imax);
t(imin);
y(imax);
y(imin);
```

Comment: actually min and max have the position as second output. So no need for find.

Comment: I have done the following (still not working but I hope i'm getting in the right direction):

1. I have saved an excel file as a txt tab delimited file. Column A being the subject nummer. Column B to I are the different values for  the parameters m1,..,m8
2. I have used import data on matlab to open this file and obtained a spreadsheet

Comment: @user1719126 btw now that I see your equation your equation I'll add it to my solution. You'll notice a bunch of added `.`s, this makes the operators element-wise and are very necessary for this application.

Comment: a probably stupid question but:
-if i open my tab delimited file do i use import selection > generate script or function?
-if i open both files i see a lot of text numbered in points do i just enter what's written and click run?

Comment: where do i put this formula and is it possible to get the maximum velocity and corresponding time in the adjascent columns?

Comment: @user1719126 you should ask further unrelated questions (like importing the data from excel) as a separate new question.

Comment: See my answer. I'm not trying to show off here, but I just wanted to let you know about finite differences for numerical differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

well as your question is a bit general I can just provide some pointers where to look.

- for the formula you could store in a `[function][1]` or `[function handle][2]`  - also there is a symbolic math toolbox that you could use (in that case you could use symbolic differentiation to find the extrema)
- Next is basically loops (see `for` or `while`) - will depend a bit in how you read your data into matlab.
- last would be finding the extrema (I suppose you don't know the exact time of them) - lookup the `fmin` command for numeric minimization (is for minima - but for maxima just use `-`your function as objective) - if there are several you might need to play a bit with it's settings.
- lets not forget some output. I think `xlswrite` is most comfortable. But help will point you to alternatives.

---

as a side note you should try to do the differentiation manually to check how many solutions you should expect.